# Flip a (loaded) coin and get a head only on the last two tosses

Tags: probability

So on this loaded coin, the probability of a head is 0.4 and a tail is 0.6, and the coin is flipped 4 times. How would I go about calculating the probability of only getting a head on flips 3 and 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT
Multiply the probability of a tail on flip 1 by the probability of a tail on flip 2 by ....

> $0.6^2\times0.4^2=0.0576$